# Alternative definition of (strongly?, weakly?) mixing

Tags: reference-request, ergodic-theory

In his paper *On Automorphisms of Compact Groups*, Halmos defines a measure preserving transformation $\alpha$ to be *ergodic* if the only complex-valued measure preserving solutions of the equation $f^\alpha = f$ are constant almost everywhere and to be *mixing* if the only measure preserving solutions of the $f^\alpha = \lambda f$ for any constant $\lambda \in \Bbb{C}$ are constant almost every where (implying that actually $\lambda = 1$). (Here $f^\alpha(x) = f(\alpha(x))$.) He refers to Hopf's *Ergodentheorie*  for proofs that these definitions are equivalent to the more common ones. I am familiar with the proof that ergodic in this sense is equivalent to ergodicity as defined by a $0$-$1$ law for $\alpha$-invariant sets. I don't have access to Hopf's book and have two questions: (1) is the given definition of mixing equivalent to strongly mixing or weakly mixing? (2) can anyone point me at a more accessible reference to the proof that this definition of mixing is equivalent to the one of the more common definitions (e.g., as given in Halmos's *Lectures on Ergodic Theory*), or, even, if it's not too long, post a proof here.

Comment: The definition you've given here is equivalent to the usual definition of "weakly mixing".  One place you can find a nice proof (at least in the case of $\mathbb{Z}$ actions) is Theorem 2.36 of Einsiedler and Ward's book

Comment: @Adam: Thanks. That's very helpful.